# CSS grid dynamic number of columns possible?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

i have a web page setup which uses css grid to display the main section centered at 80% width.

```html
<html>
....

<body>
  <main>
    <section>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
....

</html>
```

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
}

section {
  max-width: 80%;
  min-height: 100%
}
```

now I would like to also be able to add a second section using a PHP if statement so that both sections are displayed right next to each other at 50% each. (while not altering the css via PHP)
If I just add another section it will be displayed on top or below the first one.

I've already tried using `grid-auto-columns` as well as setting `grid-template-rows` to 100% but both didn't work as expected.

Any Ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: try `grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,1fr)`

Comment: thats an invalid property value according to chrome

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p58uqy00/ ... you simply need to add min-value

Comment: ok thank you that woks well for 100% or 50/50 but not for 80% or 50/50. When I try to set minmax(1fr, 80%) it will not be displayed as expected, again with the "invalid property value". With max-width: 80% there will be two boxes each filling 80% of half of the width

Comment: ok i solved it by setting max-width to 80vw instead of 80%

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you are after, but this will give you side by side,

```
<html>

  <body>
    <main>
      <section>
        section1 stuff
      </section>
      <section>
        section2 stuff
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>

main{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 200px 300px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap:5px;
}
section{
  max-width: 80%;
  min-height: 100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:red;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZovaVG

Ugly in a Pen, but it does what you asked.